# building a DataFrame of a portfolio of symbols

Tags: pandas

I'm new to pandas.

I'm like to read the quotes for a number of symbols (e.g. ['SPY', 'IWM', 'QQQ']) from Yahoo (which I do with no problem) and then I'd like to use only the 'Adj Close' columns to build a portfolio of ETFs over a given period of time.

Say that I'd like to start with an empty DataFrame whose index are the dates where the market is open, taken for example from the first df. Subsequently, I'd like to "append" to the right one single column at a time with the 'Adj Close' of each symbol, renamed with the ticker name.

I'm sure it must be simple, but I can't get it. Can anybody help me? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just using the `Adj Close` column, it is easiest to extract it immediately after reading the data.

```
import pandas.io.data as web

df = web.DataReader(['F', 'AAPL', 'IBM'], 'yahoo', '2016-05-02', '2016-05-06')['Adj Close']

>>> df
                 AAPL      F         IBM
Date                                    
2016-05-02  93.073328  13.62  143.881476
2016-05-03  94.604009  13.43  142.752373
2016-05-04  93.620002  13.31  142.871221
2016-05-05  93.239998  13.32  145.070003
2016-05-06  92.720001  13.44  147.289993
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much